# How do I retrieve data from a parent in react native using Flatlist?

Tags: react-native, react-native-flatlist

I have a flatlist in ResultsShowScreen.js and I'm trying to pass some data to a child screen when a user taps on an item in the flatlist.

```
    ResultsShowScreen.js
                        <TouchableOpacity 
                            onPress = {() => navigation.navigate('Audioplayer',  {id: item.id, name:item.name, audio_file: item.audio_file}) } >
                            <Text> {item.name}  ({item.length} min) </Text>
                            <Text> {item.short_desc} </Text>
                            <Text> {item.long_desc} </Text>
                            <Text> Avg Rating: {item.avg_rating}/5  ({item.num_ratings} ratiings) </Text>

                        </TouchableOpacity>
```

In AudioplayerScreen.js, I currently have the below and this works.

```
    const AudioplayerScreen = ( {navigation} ) => {

        // Get values from previous page
        const name = navigation.getParam('name');
        const id = navigation.getParam('id');
        const audio_file = navigation.getParam('audio_file');
```

But I'm trying to follow the tutorial here (https://amanhimself.dev/build-an-audio-player-in-react-native) by having the component in the format of

```
    export default class AudioplayerScreen extends React.Component {
        // rest of code here
```

In AudioplayerScreen.js, how do I retrieve the data being passed from the parent using the above?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can access the same `navigation` prop like so `this.props.navigation`. `react-navigation` makes sure that prop is passed when you register the screen.

**EDIT**

Here's a snippet of what that would look like:

```
export default class AudioplayerScreen extends React.Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.name = props.navigation.getParam('name');
  }
  ...
  // or outside constructor
  return <Button title={this.props.navigation.getParam('name')} ... />
}
```

Comment: I try do the below but I get a TransformError SyntaxError

export default class AudioplayerScreen extends React.Component {

    name = this.props.navigation.getParam('name');
    console.log(name);

Comment: do you think you could add a code snippet so I can see how to access 'name' for example?

Comment: You have to do that in a constructor when using a class. I can add a little snippet in the answer.